# Raspberry pi model B (pi 1} + wifi

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi-os

I have an original pi ( made in china) which I have just tried to use. But need to get wifi working, as the RJ45 is Down. It works to install pi os and configure it using a USB to RJ45 adapter but I need wifi for it's final destination.

I'm using an EDImax EW7811 USB to Wireless 802.11B/g/n adapter with Realtek RTL8188CUS chip. It reports "not associated) Ive run out of trying numerous settings including modifying wpa_supplicant.conf without success.

Has any one any experience of using this adapter with pi-os?

I have just installed the same wifi dongle on a pi-4 with the same os with no problems! Ithink the pi-1 needs something in /boot/config.txt (Bravo spotted this). lsusb picks up the dongle on both machines. Correction the pi 4 is running 64bit os

Comment: Try searching "debian usb wifi driver RTL8188CUS" - maybe you need to install one?

Comment: Thanks arduino for the response see last para just added

Comment: "config.sys"?? where is that??

Comment: Maybe it's the fact that the Pi 4 is 64 bit, so the drivers don't work on a 32 bit os???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the sugestions. The answer was found at Pi-HUT who sell a similar dongle with thwe suggestion :++

"This product no longer works with the provided driver/instructions due to a kernel change in Raspberry Pi OS. https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_armhf/images/raspios_armhf-2020-05-28/, however you won't be able to update that image. We are working on finding a new driver."

This works.